Put phyloseq plots into a grid like formation
I am writing on this forum because the phyloseq github issues page is not being answered and I need help with a very specific formating question. Ultimately, I want to have a grid of graphs like this:

where the column headers (where asia, europe, and north america are) is body site, sex, and pregnancy status, while my 3 row headers are the alpha diversity metrics (shannon, observed, and Inverse Simpson). I want to use the plot_richness function with phyloseq and create diversity metrics for each of my categories.
I achieved getting three plots for body site with the code:
alpha_body_site <- plot_richness(ps_rarefied, x="body.site", measures = c("Shannon", "Observed", "InvSimpson"), color = "body.site")

#remove phyloseq dots
alpha_body_site$layers <- alpha_body_site$layers[-1]

alpha_body_site <- alpha_body_site +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = body.site), outlier.size = -1, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = ghibli_palette("PonyoMedium")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "grey")) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold", size = 12)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "NA"), panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey90")) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA), legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.title.y.left = element_text(size = 14), axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(size = 12), axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(size = 14), axis.text.y.left = element_text(size = 12))

which creates a row of 3 alpha diversity plots by body site:

I now want to add significance bars above the box plots that are significantly different, so I thought I need to expand the y limits to create more space at the top of the plots to fit the bars. When I try to expand the y limits with ylim() it will change all 3 plots to be the same metric which throws off the box plot sizes because shannon for example only goes up to 6 while observed is from 0-1000. I believe I will need to make a separate box plot for every diversity metric to achieve the look im going for, but I want to be able to format the final figure to look like the grid of graphs I mentioned above. I was able to create the plots I want by doing the following code for each diversity metric:
shannon_alpha_body_site <- plot_richness(ps_rarefied, x="body.site", measures = c("Shannon"), color = "body.site") + ylim(1,6.6)

shannon_alpha_body_site$layers <- shannon_alpha_body_site$layers[-1]

shannon_alpha_body_site <- shannon_alpha_body_site +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = body.site), outlier.size = -1, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = ghibli_palette("PonyoMedium")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "grey")) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold", size = 12)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "NA"), panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey90")) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA), legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.title.y.left = element_text(size = 14), axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(size = 14), axis.text.y.left = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2) + stat_pvalue_manual(shannon_df_filtered, y.position = c(5.5,6,6.5), hide.ns = TRUE, label = "p.signif", position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL)


I see people use facet_grid() to create the grid look, but I can't figure out how to make it work with separate plots, or  re-format my data in a way that would make this grid work. Is there a way I can achieve this grid look, while also having the significance bars for each plot? Thanks for your help.

In a very much simplified example (taken from ?phyloseq::plot_richness), you can take a ggplot that has already been faceted and re-do the faceting with facet grid. The measures are in the column "variable" of the plot's dataframe.
library(phyloseq)
library(ggplot2)
data("soilrep")

p1 <- plot_richness(soilrep, 
              measures = c("Shannon", "Observed", "InvSimpson"), 
) 

print(p1)

# what variables are available in the data
colnames(p1$data)

p1 +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(variable), # measures
             cols = vars(Treatment) # 
  )


Hi Michiel,
Thank you for your reply! When I try that code, I get a plot like this:http://127.0.0.1:44619/graphics/80f37cfb-e3f8-4342-9208-3b68fb36672a.png

127.0.0.0.1 is your local machine, we can't see that. I know what it looks like though, since I made it. Does it not illustrate the principle?

I understand this is showing a way to put the plot_richness in facet_grid, however I can't figure out how to use my already made plots to do this even though you showed the general idea. I am not the best at R so it's not intuitive to me how to re-format this to work with my data. If I used my already made plots (for example shannon_alpha_body_site) and add the facet_grid(rows = vars(variable), cols = vars(body.site), it throws an error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (24)."

To make it work with your data, we'd need a  minimal reproducible example (MRE). I get that you may be unable to share a full dataset, but perhaps you can write some code that allows us to create a synthetic one? I usually just throw something together quickly with a variation on
n_rows <- 1000
fake_data <- data.frame(
name = sample(LETTERS, n_rows, replace = TRUE),
value = runif(n_rows, 0, 1)
)
